# WordPress Ajax callback function from plugin - OOP

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, oop

Using [PluginBoilerplate](https://github.com/omarabid/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) to write a plugin.
I need to make an ajax call.

I added to main `plugin.php` file, class to register scripts and handle ajax calls.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX' ) ) {

class PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX{
    public static $instance = null;
    public $nonce = '';
    public $name = 'ajaxexample';
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        null === self::$instance AND self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function __construct(){
        # Could as well be: wp_enqueue_scripts or login_enqueue_scripts
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scriptsEnqueue' ) );
        # Logged in users:
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'scriptsRegister' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scriptsLocalize' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'ajaxRegister' ) );


    }
    public function scriptsRegister( $page ){
        $file = 'page-1.js';
        wp_register_script(
            $this->name ,
            WPBP_URLPATH . '/app/files/js/' . $file ,
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
    public function scriptsEnqueue( $page ){

        wp_enqueue_script( $this->name );
    }

    public function ajaxRegister() {
        add_action( "wp_ajax_{$this->name}_action",  array($this, 'ajaxexample'), '1' );
    }

    public function scriptsLocalize( $page ){
        wp_localize_script( $this->name, "{$this->name}Object", array(
            'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'action'           => "{$this->name}_action"
        ) );
    }

   public function ajaxexample(){
        ob_clean();

        echo json_encode( array(
            'success' => true
        ) );
        wp_die();   
    }
}
}
```

the class being called after vendor/autoload.php is included.

**the main issue** is that although the script is successfully registered, enqueued and localized, the ajax callback function is not taking action.

ajax call is returning empty response.

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
           $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#moreroles').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                /* Act on the event */
                var data = plugin;
                $.ajax({
                    url: plugin.ajax_url,
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend : function( d ) {
                        console.log( 'Before send', d );
                     }
                })
                .done( function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX done', textStatus, jqXHR, jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                } )
                .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX failed', jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), textStatus, errorThrown );
                } )
                .then( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( 'AJAX after finished', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
                } );

            });
    } );
} )( jQuery, ajaxexampleObject || {});
```

Comment: Your `data` points to `data` variable that holds `plugin`. What is `plugin`? You'd need something like `data: {'action': 'ajax_function_callback', 'data': data_to_send}` inside the `$.ajax` function...

Comment: please take a look at my editing. i refer to plugin as ajaxexampleObject.

Comment: In your php you have `add_action( "wp_ajax_{$this->name}_action",  array($this, 'ajaxexample'), '1' );` so the action is to call is `ajaxexample`. But in your js you have: `$.ajax({url: plugin.ajax_url, data: data, ...})`, where `data` is set to `plugin` and you should have `ajaxexample` as an action to call...

Comment: Plugin is ajaxrxampleObject. Take a look at my resent editing. Anyway it's not the issue. Plugin variable get the parameters from php correctly.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't notice it. In the WordPress plugin boilerplate there was a similar issue. I couldn't get ajax to load no matter how I registered the callback function. In the end I removed it from the class and put the `wp_ajax` hook and the callback function in the plugin root file. Also are you using this on the back end or front? Because you also need `wp_ajax_nopriv` hook for the front end.

Comment: @dingo_d - i managed to register wp_ajax_{$this->name}_action when i called if not only  `new PoorMansNameSpaceAJAX();` on admin page, but also `$spaceAJAX->getInstance(); ` i'm using this only on admin page for your question.

Comment: @AmitRahav, did you fix this? Where are you instantiating this class? are you sure you are not reaching `ajaxexample`?

Answer (score 0):

[PluginBoilerplate](https://github.com/omarabid/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) is missing the correct handling process for this kind of usage.
[This OOP WP Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.io/) does it much better, and provides loader classes for admin and client.